# @SpyBean not support circular bean

Tags: mockito, spring-boot-test, spybean

springboot version：2.4.13
spring-boot-starter-test version: 2.4.13
question
when use  @SpyBean ,it not support circular bean
eg:

```
public class A {
    @Autowired
    private B b;

    public String getName() {
        return A.class.getName();
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return 18;
    }
}
public class B {
    @Autowired
    private A a;

    public String getName() {
        return B.class.getName();
    }
}
public class TestCycle {
    @SpyBean
    private A a;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Mockito.doReturn("name").when(a).getName();
        Assertions.assertEquals("name", a.getName());
        Assertions.assertEquals(18, a.getAge());
    }
}
```

exception:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'a': Bean with name 'a' has been injected into other beans [b] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesForType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.

i want support circular bean when use @SpyBean